# Python script for object and class did not run

Tags: python, class, object

I have a problem with line 14 and 15

I tried creating an object with a class by name "Person" but when I run the script, it tells me AttributeError

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, complexion, hobby):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.complexion = complexion
        self.hobby = hobby


def introduce_self(self):
    print("My name is" ,self.name, self.weight , "in weight," ,self.complexion,"in complexion," , "and I do" ,self.hobby, "for relaxation")


p1 = ("Shereden", 30, "fair", "watching Cumcumbagyea")
p2 = ("Stephen", 40, "dark", "surfing the net")

p1.introduce_self()
p2.introduce_self()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Opeemu/Hello_world.py", line 14, in <module>
    p1.introduce_self()
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'introduce_self'
```

Comment: Please try to write questions in a human-readable format. Also, it's `def __init__(self, ...): ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `p1` and `p2` as `sets` and not as `Person` objects.

What you want is:

```
p1 = Person("Shereden", 30, "fair", "watching Cumcumbagyea")
p2 = Person("Stephen", 40, "dark", "surfing the net")
```

Also make sure your indentation is correct for the `introduce_self` method

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the object first before using any of the objects methods.

```
p1 = ("Shereden", 30, "fair", "watching Cumcumbagyea")
p2 = ("Stephen", 40, "dark", "surfing the net")
```

Also, the init function should be:

```
def __init__(self, name, weight, complexion, hobby): ...
```

Otherwise it will be another method that you can call like p1.init()